# Is there a presentation for the symmetries of the circle?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, infinite-groups

If we take the group that is the real points on the unit circle on the plane under rotations and reflections for symmetry. Is this group $D_\infty $? Can it be generated by $\{ r,s\}$, and if so does it have a presentation similar to $D_{2n}$ for n finite?

Comment: Note that the circle group has uncountably many elements, and a finite presentation can generate only countably many group elements.

Comment: Have you considered the set of continuous bijections of the circle to itself? That would be closed under composition and (I think) inverses, so it would form a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any finitely (or countably) generated group would only be countable. The group is isomorphic to $S^1\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ which is similar to the isomorphism $D_{2n}\approx \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, though. The question is: Which group would you prefer to call $D_\infty$? $S^1\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or maybe $\mathbb Z\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? The last at least shares the property of having a cyclic subgroup of index 2; also, it has a corresponding presentation $\langle\,r,s\mid s^2=1, srs=r^{-1}\,\rangle$. That's why (in spite of your idea that is inspired by geometric intuition of polygons converging to the circle) it is the last of these groups, $\mathbb Z\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$,  that is called infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_dihedral_group), this can be called a generalized dihedral group.